# SSRS Null Date Multi-Filtering

Tags: sql, date, reporting-services, filtering

I have a table with three columns: Task, Assigned To and Due Date. I want to set a filter to Due Date where every date is greater than or equal to today's date. I can't post any photos, but the filter is easy enough to understand. The filter looks like this:

> Due_Date >=Today()

My problem is **I want to include null or blank dates**, and I'm finding this to be tricky by using SSRS filters.

How can I include all dates greater than or equal to today's date or null values?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an OR with your other conditions (NULL or Blank):

```
=IIF(FIELDS!Due_Date.VALUE >=Today OR ISNOTHING(FIELDS!Due_Date.VALUE) OR FIELDS!Due_Date.VALUE = "", True, False)
```